# How do I know if my device's GPU (or graphics driver) is of subpar quality?

Tags: gpu, graphics

The other day I got a new tablet.  It's an [Insignia Flex 10.1](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-flex-10-1-16gb-silver-white/6086148.p?id=1219660450840&), a bargain Best Buy brand.  A tablet's a tablet, though.

Then I noticed, across several apps, this weird texture bleeding:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge for better resolution)</sub>

[image: IMG: Notice the text]

Notice the text. This didn't happen when playing this game on a different device.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge for better resolution)</sub>

[image: IMG: Notice the dots]

Notice the dots.

**Is this indicative of a cheap, crappy GPU or bad OpenGL drivers?**  Or is it a coincidence and that the developers for these two apps use the same bad OpenGL techniques?  And by cheap and crappy I mean *bad*, not just mediocre or underpowered.

Comment: You could try some benchmarking app for comparing your GPU standards. Antutu has a good app for that. Try that and test your device's GPU and 3D performance rating.

Comment: I did, actually.  Yes, my GPU is subpar, but on further consideration that's not really what I'm asking about.  Let me revise the title.